Display stretching issue in surface pro 7 in Ubuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu on my surface pro 7 and everything was going fine until I tried to change my resolution in settings.so basically when I lower my resolution I get these black bars.i tried to use many commands and tutorials but none worked.any ideas?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

The latest version

You mean 24.04?

Anyway, try installing the Linux Surface kernels https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface

I will reply to you after I install the kernel

Please mention the versiion of ubuntu

Its version 24.04

im having this error while installing the surface kernel: loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first

Glad to know that the previous issue is fixed. If everything works without surface kernel, then you don't have to use it. If you want to use a surface kernel, please open a GitHub issue

i fixed the resolution issue by using a custom resolution like in my monitor for example my laptops screen aspect ratio is 3:2 so by using a 3:2 resolution i am streching it with no issue.the resolution is (1624x1080) resolution.just google 3:2 resolutions if u dont want the resolution i provided and use xrandr commands-                         cvt 1620 1080
> infos...
xrandr --newmode "1624x1080_60.00"  145.50  1624 1728 1896 2168  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --current
> Screen profiles/resolutions
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1624x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1624x1080_60.00"

the alternative 1500x1000 command:
cvt 1500 1000
> infos...
xrandr --newmode "1500x1000_60.00"  145.50  1624 1728 1896 2168  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --current
> Screen profiles/resolutions
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1500x1000_60.00"
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1500x1000_60.00"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
